# Spring boot Java post request

Tags: java, reactjs, http, spring-boot

I am trying to do a simple post request from React (client side) to Java server side. Here is my controller below.

```
package com.va.med.dashboard.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import com.va.med.dashboard.services.VistaServiceImpl;
import gov.va.med.exception.FoundationsException;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/dashboard")
public class DashboardController  {

   @Autowired
   private VistaServiceImpl vistaService;

   @RequestMapping("/main")
   String home() {
          return "main route";
   }

   @RequestMapping("/rpc")
   String test() throws FoundationsException {
          vistaService.myAuth();
          return "this is rpc route";
   }

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = 
"application/json", value = "/vista")
   @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
   public String getVistaConnection(@RequestBody String ipString, @RequestBody String portString, @RequestBody String accessPin,
   @RequestBody String verifyPin) {

       System.out.println(ipString);
       System.out.println(portString);
       System.out.println(accessPin);
       System.out.println(verifyPin);

       vistaService.connect(ipString, portString, accessPin, verifyPin); // TO-DO populate with serialized vars
       if (vistaService.connected) {
              return "Connected";
       } else {
              return "Not Connected";
       }
   }
}
```

Below is my react axios post request

```
 axios.post('/dashboard/vista', {
  ipString: this.state.ipString,
  portString: this.state.portString,
  accessPin: this.state.accessPin,
  verifyPin: this.state.verifyPin
})
.then(function (response){
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error){
  console.log(error);
});
```

This is also the error that I am getting.

```
Failed to read HTTP message:     
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: 
Required request body is missing:
```

Can anyone please shed some light on this error message? I'm coming from a pure JavaScript background so a lot of things I just don't know for Java because it is automatically implemented inside of JavaScrips language.

Thanks again in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You're doing it wrong.

Instead of

```
public String getVistaConnection(@RequestBody String ipString, @RequestBody String portString, @RequestBody String accessPin,RequestBody String verifyPin)
```

You should wrap those parameters in a class:

```
public class YourRequestClass {
   private String ipString;
   private String portString;
   ....
   // Getter/setters here
}
```

and your controller method will look like:

```
public String getVistaConnection(@RequestBody YourRequestClass request)
```

From @Rajmani Arya:

Since RestContoller and `@RequestBody` suppose to read JSON body, so in your `axios.post` call you should put headers `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: Since `RestContoller` and `@RequestBody` suppose to read JSON body, so in your axios call you should put headers `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: Good catch! I'll add this

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace all @RequestBody annotations with @RequestParam

```
public String getVistaConnection(@RequestParam String ipString, @RequestParam String portString, @RequestParam String accessPin, @RequestParam String verifyPin)
```

Comment: When I try this It says "required String parameter ipString is not present". I believe I have the correct spelling on each thing i've looked it over a few times.